# Android app cache removed when device rebooted or app is closed

Tags: android, html5-appcache

I am creating a html 5 application which use app cache to work application in offline mode.HTML 5 website is working fine when opens in browser.

I also created an android app for the website and simply opening the website in webview control. App is working fine in online mode and also storing data in offline mode. But problem is when I completely closed the app from task manager or device is rebooted, then the offline data get lost.

Is there any way to store the data when device rebooted or app closed completely?

Any help appreciated Thanks in Advance

Comment: Storing data using Sqlite or Shared preference can be a option.

Comment: I got the answer for that, Now I am saving the cache in the database in the Android device. It is working fine for me.